# "Boomerang" words in Spanish

Tags: etimología, solicitud-de-término, préstamo-lingüístico

I recently found out that *aligátor*, from English *alligator*, came originally from a corruption of *el lagarto*:

> ## [aligátor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1r7Qz06)
>
> Quizá del fr. *alligator*, este del ingl. *alligator*, y este del esp. *el lagarto.*
>
> 1. `m.` [**caimán**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6dcNNCr#2rhLsjx) (‖ reptil).

Are there any other ['boomerang'](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/05/28/boomerang-vocabulary/) words in Spanish? I.e. words which originated in Spanish, were loaned to another language, and then returned as a new word.